# How to batch rename files in folder

Tags: bash, filenames, rename

I have a zip file where each file is named the following

```
original.jpg.1.png
original.jpg.2.png
```

The files are actually jpegs
How do I go about renaming them to the following?

```
original1.jpg
original2.jpg
```

Comment: Wait, I completely missed an important word here; you have zip files that contain these filenames. Do you want to *extract* the zip file(s) to new filenames, or do you want to (end up with) renamed files *inside* the zip file?  Or do you just have plain directories?

Comment: As the hint of the downarrow says: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 2):

With prename (perl rename):

```
rename 's/original.jpg.(\d+).png/original$1.jpg/' original.jpg.*.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Location of the zip file
zip_file="/path/to/jpegs.zip"
#Desired location of extracted files
dest_dir="/path/to/extract"

#Unzip the file to the desired location
unzip "$zip_file" -d "$dest_dir"

for f in "$dest_dir/"*.png; do
    #Remove path from filename.
    filename=$(basename "$f")
    #Remove .jpg. from filename.
    filename=${filename/.jpg./}
    #Change .png to .jpg
    filename=${filename/.png/.jpg}
    #Rename the extracted files to the preferred naming convention using mv.
    mv "$f" "${dest_dir}/${filename}"
done
```